# Unix find and sort with wildcards

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, find

let's suppose i've a folder with some xml file:

- a-as-jdbc.xml
- z-as-jdbc.xml
- fa-jdbc.xml
- config.xml
- router.xml
- paster.xml
- cleardown.xml

I would like to pipe the find with some kind of sort command using wildcards and my custom sorting logic.

That because I want that the order of the filename returned will be always the same.

For example, i want always:

- 1 element: "config.xml"
- 2 element: "*.as-jdbc.xml"
- 3 element: "*-jdbc.xml" (excluding pattern "*.as-jdbc")
- 4 element: "router.xml"
- and so on...

How can i achieve this? Any idea?
I did it in the past using arrays but don't remember exactly how i did now...

Thanks

Comment: I dont clearly see the pattern you want, could you try to clarify that?

Comment: The pattern to follow is exactly the order i put in the example, i want the LS output sorted always like that: firstly the config.xml then  "*.as-jdbc.xml" then "-jdbc.xml" (excluding pattern ".as-jdbc") and so on...

Comment: And what about paster and cleardown?

Comment: I did not put all the order, but let's say that after ".as-jdbc" will follow cleardown.xml and paster.xml :)

Comment: `perl` lets you specify a custom-sort function, that lets you define criterial for 'before'  and 'after' almost arbitrarily.

Comment: You aren't sorting so much as arranging; there is nothing about the name "router.xml", for example, that explains why it should appear after the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too pretty but :

rules.txt:

```
config\.xml
.*\.as\-jdbc\.xml
^[^-]*\-jdbc\.xml
router\.xml
```

Commands:

```
$ find /path/to/dir > /tmp/result.txt
$ cat rules.txt | xargs -I{} grep -E "{}" /tmp/result.txt
config.xml
a-as-jdbc.xml
z-as-jdbc.xml
fa-jdbc.xml
router.xml
```

You will have to add the two others patterns needed for `paster` and `cleardown`

Comment: Thanks all guys, all answer looks good and helpfull, but this one permit me to modify the order without change the script... i'm going to test it! :)

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly easier to do this in a higher level language like Python.

This is not a sorting problem; it is an ordering problem. As such, you cannot use the Unix sort command.

Inevitably, you will need to make 4 passes anyway so I would do either:

```
$ find /tmp/alex -name config.xml ; \
> find /tmp/alex -name *-as-jdbc.xml ; \
> find /tmp/alex \( \! -name *-as-jdbc.xml -a -name *-jdbc.xml \) ; \
> find /tmp/alex \( -type f -a \! -name config.xml -a \! -name *-jdbc.xml \)
/tmp/alex/config.xml
/tmp/alex/a-as-jdbc.xml
/tmp/alex/z-as-jdbc.xml
/tmp/alex/fa-jdbc.xml
/tmp/alex/cleardown.xml
/tmp/alex/paster.xml
/tmp/alex/router.xml
```

Or use grep:

```
$ find /tmp/alex -type f > /tmp/aaa
$ grep /config.xml /tmp/aaa ; \
> grep -- -as-jdbc.xml /tmp/aaa ; \
> grep -- -jdbc.xml /tmp/aaa | grep -v -- -as-jdbc.xml ; \
> egrep -v '(?:config.xml|-jdbc.xml)' /tmp/aaa
/tmp/alex/config.xml
/tmp/alex/a-as-jdbc.xml
/tmp/alex/z-as-jdbc.xml
/tmp/alex/fa-jdbc.xml
/tmp/alex/cleardown.xml
/tmp/alex/paster.xml
/tmp/alex/router.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just putting your **find** commands in the order you want:

```
$ find . -name config.xml; \
> find . -name \*.as-jdbc.xm; \
> find . -name \*-jdbc.xml -a ! -name \*as-jdbc.xml; \
> find . -name router.xml; \
> ... and so on.
```